# BuddyPress notification list anchor tag URL set wrong

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

I am working on a website which is build in wordpress. In that the theme is "Buddy-boss" and also used plugin buddypress and bbpress. bbpress plugin is used for forum. The issue is that when user click on any forum related notification from the notification list then it throws 404 Not Found error. The link which is set on the forum notification is something like below :

```
www.xyz.com/host/admin-ajax.php/?action=bbp_mark_read&topic_id=0&reply_id=11713&_wpnonce=2263b41479#post-11713
```

Here above link with "xyz.com" is a dummy just to show the link which is build.Can't disclose the domain name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, if you cannot disclosure the real website, a demo website would be helpful

Comment: I have not any demo site. But you can see the demo site for notification which is provided by buddyboss theme. Here is the url : https://demos.buddyboss.com/online-communities/members/john/notifications/read/

Comment: You can create a sandobox testing site over there. and the issue which is of notification is related to the forum only.

Comment: If you are using the a BuddyBoss theme, then you should use the BuddyBoss Platform - **not** BuddyPress.  The BuddyBoss Platform includes forums.